# Event on Home/End keys pressed using cell editing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

Using Ag-Grid 8.1.1 (free version) and AngularJS 1.5.8

I have an editable grid.

The default behavior of the grid is `Use home and end to go to the first and last rows.` (See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/?framework=angularjs)

My problem is: while editing a cell, I press the End key to go to the end of the input. And the grid scroll down to the last row.

How can I override this behavior ?

What I did so far:

```
  onCellEditingStarted: function(gridEvent) {
      $($element).on('keydown.grid', function(jqueryEvent) {
        jqueryEvent.stopPropagation();
        jqueryEvent.preventDefault();
        if (e.key === 'End') {
          myCustomFunction();
        }
      });
    },
```

`myCustomFunction` is called, but the default behavior of the grid is not stoped by `e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Did you try `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();` instead of `e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @akash `event` is not a JQuery event but an ag-grid event. It is build like this `{node: RowNode, data: Object, value: "Nombre", rowIndex: 1, column: Column…}`. I change the name in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest answer is set `cellEditor: 'popupText'` for each column that you want to be able to use the home and end buttons. Here's a [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/TFDNklCZlRX0Xar6qCXO/) that demonstrates that behavior. I am not sure if this will be viewed as a bug/defect by the developers, but it at least works up to v 9.

Comment: Works great ! Thanks ;)